# rails, Cannot run sidekiq

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sidekiq

I have created `sidekiq.yml` file inside config folder:

```
---
:concurrency: 25
:pidfile: ./tmp/pids/sidekiq.pid
:logfile: ./log/sidekiq.log
:queues:
  -default
```

I have added `foreman` gem in my Rails project and created Procfile in my root folder:

```
web: bundle exec rails s
worker: sidekiq -C config/sidekiq.yml
```

When I run foreman in my command line it just does not want to start. Messages are:

```
C:\Users\lenovo\RubymineProjects\new-seeker-test>foreman start
11:41:39 web.1    | started with pid 8088
11:41:39 worker.1 | started with pid 7920
11:41:40 web.1    | DL is deprecated, please use Fiddle
11:41:40 worker.1 | undefined method `each' for "-default":String
11:41:40 worker.1 | D:/Ruby21-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/sidekiq-   3.3.4/lib/sidekiq/cli.rb:378:in `parse_queues'
11:41:40 worker.1 | D:/Ruby21-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/sidekiq-  3.3.4/lib/sidekiq/cli.rb:363:in `parse_config'
11:41:40 worker.1 | D:/Ruby21-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/sidekiq-3.3.4/lib/sidekiq/cli.rb:212:in `setup_options'
11:41:40 worker.1 | D:/Ruby21-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/sidekiq-3.3.4/lib/sidekiq/cli.rb:38:in `parse'
11:41:40 worker.1 | D:/Ruby21-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/sidekiq-3.3.4/bin/sidekiq:7:in `<top (required)>'
11:41:40 worker.1 | D:/Ruby21-x64/bin/sidekiq:23:in `load'
11:41:40 worker.1 | D:/Ruby21-x64/bin/sidekiq:23:in `<main>'
11:41:40 worker.1 | exited with code 1
11:41:40 system   | sending SIGKILL to all processes
11:41:40 system   | sending SIGKILL to web.1 at pid 8088
11:41:40 web.1    | exited with code 0
```

I think there is something on `11:41:40 worker.1 | undefined method 'each' for "-default":String`

My ruby version is 2.1.5
Rails version is 4.2.0
Windows 7 x64

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The queues list in your YAML file is invalid.  You need a space after the dash.

https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq/wiki/Advanced-Options#the-sidekiq-configuration-file